# How to trigger an action in a child Angular 1.5 component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular 1.5 component with another enclosed child component.
What is the best way to trigger an action in the child controller from the parent and pass a payload as a parameter?

I know I can watch for a change of a data item via the child's $onChange lifecycle hook, but I would prefer a "push" abstraction (like calling a child's method from the parent) rather than "pull" abstraction (like child reacting to a change of the paren's property).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$broadcast` for this. It should solve the purpose.